# Problema con Trying to get property of non-object Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

soy nuevo en programación y en stackoverflow y es estoy obteniendo este error

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>       Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/hernan/laravel/Store/Tienda/resources/views/user/compra_producto/index.blade.php)

Les explico lo que quiero hacer...
tengo un catalogo de productos donde listo mis productos

```
@foreach($productos as $pro)
@if($pro->emp_activo==1)
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 portfolio-item">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top img-rounded" src="{{asset('imagenes/productos/'.$pro->pro_foto)}}"  height="200px" alt=""></a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">
                <a href="#">{{$pro->pro_nom}}</a>
            </h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{$pro->pro_info}}</p>
            <p><b>Tienda:</b> {{$pro->empresa}}<br>
                @if ($pro->pro_ofer_active==1)
                <b>Precio: </b><strike style="color: red;">{{$pro->pro_precio}}</strike> | <b>Oferta: </b>{{$pro->pro_oferta}}
                @else
                <b>Precio: </b>{{$pro->pro_precio}}
                @endif
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" style="margin: auto;">
            <span><a href="{{ url('/comprar',array($pro->pro_id)) }}" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><i class="fa fa-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"></i> Comprar</a></span>
            <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-info"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> ({{$pro->pro_megusta}}) </button></span>
            <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> ({{$pro->pro_nomegusta}})</button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
@include('user.producto.modal')
@endforeach
```

como se puede ver mas arriba hay un boton para comprar un producto y lo que hago es obtener el id de ese producto para trabajarlo en otra vista. Luego trato de usar ese id porque debo guardarlo en otra tabla pero me da el error " Trying to get property of non-object " cuando trato de imprimirlo en pantalla

esta es la vista en donde quiero el id para trabajarlo y es cuando me da el error especificamente en esta linea

## {{$pro->pro_id}}

```
    <div class="container">
    @foreach($producto as $pro)
     <h1>{{$pro->pro_id}}</h1>
    @endforeach
    <h1>Realizar pedido</h1>
    @include('user.compra_producto.form', ['compra' => $compra, 'url' => '/comprar', 'method' => 'POST'])
</div>
```

tambien les paso mi controlador

```
public function store(Request $request) {
        $compra = new Mensaje;
        $compra->celular = $request->celular;
        $compra->mensaje = $request->mensaje;
        $compra->nombre = $request->nombre;
        $compra->ciudad = $request->ciudad;
        $compra->leido = 0;
        $compra->producto_pro_id = $request->producto_pro_id;
        $compra->users_id = 1;

        if($compra -> save()) {
            session()->flash('notificacion', 'Pedido realizado con exito!..');
            return redirect()->back();
        } else {
            return view('user.compra_producto.index', ['compra' => $compra ]);
        }
    }

    public function show($id) {
        $compra = new Mensaje;
        $producto = Producto::find($id);
        return view('user.compra_producto.index', compact('compra', 'producto'));
    }
```

y esta es mi ruta

```
Route::resource('comprar', 'CompraProductoController');
```

En la funcion show de mi controlador trabajo con dos modelos porque el id del producto quiero guardarlo en una tabla llamada mensaje..

Por favor si alguien puede darme una mano con esto y disculpen de ante mano si formule mal la pregunta.. 
observacion: el id del producto pasa a la vista.. solo que no puedo utilizarlo para ponerlo en un h1 por ejemplo

Comment: Ese error pasa cuando tratas de hacer una consulta en Laravel de un objeto y este no tiene nada que mostrar desde su atributos, tambien ocurre cuando haces una relacion y la otra tabla no devuelve ningun contenido: ahora viendo el archivo controler tienes un error: esta creando una instancia del objeto $compra con el modelo Mensaje, espero que declares ese modelo en la cabecera, el punto es que envias ese objeto a la vista a traves de compact() y si estas pidiendo algun atributo este reportara un error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre que uses una condición de búsqueda (ya sea en `find()`, `where()` etc... ) utiliza el método `->get()` para recibir toda la query.

```
$producto = Producto::find($id)->get();
```

Comment: La respuesta es muy equivoca, mi voto de -1;

Comment: Y cual sería la respuesta correcta? @Shassain

Comment: Jose muchas gracias, me funciono perfecto

Answer (score 2):

```
 @foreach($producto as $pro)
```

Esa es la linea que esta causando el error, y basicamente es porque cuando realizas un **find** el orm te retorna el objecto y tu estas intentando tratarlo como un array.

te funciona la respuesta de @Jorgesys porque al hacer el get estas pidiendole al ORM que te retorne un array de objectos, pero no es lo correcto.

Importante que entiendas esto:

**find**: retorna el objecto (Product).

**get**: retorna un array de objectos (Array[Product]).